# React life-cycle method componentDidMount() not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, client-side, react-lifecycle

I am very new to React and currently working on this hackernews app. I am following the instructions given in the book "the road to learn react" to build this app. However, the react life-cycle method componentDidMount() does not seem to be working as the console.log inside it is not being displayed. I have followed every instruction properly and double checked them. Still, I am unable to figure out the reason. Any help would be much appreciated.

My App.js file's code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
const fetch=require("node-fetch");
const DEFAULT_QUERY='redux';
const PATH_BASE='https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1';
const PATH_SEARCH='/search';
const PARAM='query=';
//const url=`${PATH_BASE}${PATH_SEARCH}?${PARAM}${DEFAULT_QUERY}`

function isSearched(searchTerm){
  return function(item){
    return !searchTerm||item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
  }
}

class App extends React.Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      result:null,
    searchTerm:DEFAULT_QUERY
    }

    this.fetchTopStories=this.fetchTopStories.bind(this);
    this.setSearchTopStories=this.setSearchTopStories.bind(this);
    this.onDismiss=this.onDismiss.bind(this);
    this.onSearchChange=this.onSearchChange.bind(this);
   }

  setSearchTopStories({result}){
    this.setState({result});
  }

   fetchTopStories(searchTerm){
   fetch(`${PATH_BASE}${PATH_SEARCH}?${PARAM}${searchTerm}`)
    .then(response=>response.json())
    .then(result=>this.setSearchTopStories(result));
  }


  onDismiss(id){
      const isNotId=item=>item.ObjectID!==id;
      const updatedList=this.state.list.filter(isNotId);
      this.setState({list:updatedList});
  }

  onSearchChange(event){

    this.setState({searchTerm:event.target.value});
  }

  componentDidMount(){ //NOT WORKING
    console.log("MOUNTED");
    const {searchTerm}=this.state;
    this.fetchTopStories(searchTerm);

  }

  render(){
    const {result,searchTerm}=this.state
    if(!result){return null;}
    return(
     <div className="page">
       <div className="interactions">

       <Search
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={this.onSearchChange}
       >Search</Search>
       </div>

       <Table 
       list={result.hits}
       pattern={searchTerm}
       onDismiss={this.onDismiss}/>

    </div>
    );
  }

}

const Search=({value,onChange,children})=>{

  return(

    <form>
    {children}<input type="text"
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}/>
    </form>
  )}


const Table=({list,pattern,onDismiss})=>
  <div className="table">
    {
        list.filter(isSearched(pattern)).map(item=>
        <div key={item.ObjectID} className="table-row">
          <span style={{width:'40%'}}>
            <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
          </span>
          <span style={{width:'30%'}}>{item.author}</span>
          <span style={{width:'10%'}}>{item.comments}</span>
          <span style={{width:'10%'}}>{item.points}</span>
          <span style={{width:'10%'}}>
            <Button onClick={()=>onDismiss(item.ObjectID)}
            className="button-inline">Dismiss</Button>
          </span>
        </div>
      )
    }
    </div>


const Button=({onClick,className='',children})=>{

    return(
      <button
      type="button"
    onClick={onClick}
    className={className}>{children}</button>

    )
  }




export default App;
```

Note: Ignore the onDismiss() function, it still needs a work around.

Comment: are you using serverside rendering

Comment: Console.log, in your case seems to be working fine, I also added alert. you can check this link  https://codesandbox.io/s/white-tdd-kib4j?file=/src/App.js 
Are you using ssr?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri No, it is rendered on the client side

Comment: @VinodSai Yeah, but why is it not being displayed on the console? Also, I am not using SSR. Its client side.

Comment: its showing in console, can you check that code @NishanthB.S

Comment: might be you console settings has some filters, so it is not showing

Comment: Hey @VinodSai Thanks! There were a few silly mistakes in my code. That's why it wasn't working. Your code helped me realize that the problem wasn't in the componentDidMount() method. Now its working :)

Comment: @VinodSai I would, but it seems I need to have at least 15 reps to upvote a comment and unfortunately I don't have that many yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the `setSearchTopStories()` function parameter. Why do you restructure the `result` parameter?

**Try this instead:**

```js
setSearchTopStories(result){
    this.setState({result});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that some other code is actually creating your `App` class.
Putting `console.log` inside the `constructor` should help You with this.

The code You are searching for should looks like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Yes, that code is pre-built in the application. That doesn't seem to be the problem.